# Getting OSError: [Errno 16] Device or resource busy: ' when using tf.keras.models.Sequential.fit_generator

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I modified a code that I found here:
https://github.com/geifmany/cifar-vgg/blob/master/cifar100vgg.py
so that it works with `tf.keras`, but when I use `fit_generator` I get the  Device or resources busy error. 
I tried with `tf.keras.models.Sequential.fit` and I do not get this error.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np
import os

from keras.datasets import cifar100
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPool2D, BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers
from tensorflow.keras import regularizers

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as keras

def build_model(): 

def normalize(x,y):

def main():
    batch_size = 128
    maxepochs = 250
    learning_rate = 0.1
    lr_decay = 1e-6
    lr_drop = 20

    tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)
    os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = '0'

    (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar100.load_data()
    x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
    x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
    x_train, x_test = normalize(x_train, x_test)

    y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
    y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)

    model = build_model()

    def lr_scheduler(epoch):
        return learning_rate * (0.5 ** (epoch // lr_drop))

    reduce_lr = keras.callbacks.LearningRateScheduler(lr_scheduler)

    datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        featurewise_center=False,  # set input mean to 0 over the dataset
        samplewise_center=False,  # set each sample mean to 0
        featurewise_std_normalization=False,  # divide inputs by std of the dataset
        samplewise_std_normalization=False,  # divide each input by its std
        zca_whitening=False,  # apply ZCA whitening
        rotation_range=15,  # randomly rotate images in the range (degrees, 0 to 180)
        width_shift_range=0.1,  # randomly shift images horizontally (fraction of total width)
        height_shift_range=0.1,  # randomly shift images vertically (fraction of total height)
        horizontal_flip=True,  # randomly flip images
        vertical_flip=False)  # randomly flip images

    datagen.fit(x_train)


    sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=learning_rate, decay=lr_decay, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])

    model.fit_generator(datagen.flow(x_train, y_train,
                                 batch_size=batch_size),
                    steps_per_epoch=None,
                    epochs=maxepochs,
                    use_multiprocessing=False,
                    validation_data=(x_test, y_test), callbacks=[reduce_lr], verbose=1)
```

this is the error that I get when the training is finished (after 250 epochs):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "/BS/work/anaconda3/envs/gpu/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/util.py", line 262, in _run_finalizers
    finalizer()

File "/BS/work/anaconda3/envs/gpu/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/util.py", line 186, in __call__
    res = self._callback(*self._args, **self._kwargs)

File "/BS/work/anaconda3/envs/gpu/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 486, in rmtree
    _rmtree_safe_fd(fd, path, onerror)

File "/BS/work/anaconda3/envs/gpu/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 444, in _rmtree_safe_fd
    onerror(os.unlink, fullname, sys.exc_info())

File "/BS/work/anaconda3/envs/gpu/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 442, in _rmtree_safe_fd
    os.unlink(name, dir_fd=topfd)

OSError: [Errno 16] Device or resource busy: '.nfs00000000000890d30000a675'
```

Answer (score 2):

It’s trying to remove some temporary directory used to communicate between processes, but the directory is mounted over NFS and some file in it is open.  NFS doesn’t support the otherwise-common Unix idiom of unlinking a file while it’s open, so the NFS client emulates it by renaming the file instead and truly removes it after the file is closed.

Recursive removal defeats this, of course, by trying to remove the renamed file as well.  In some cases, it just renames it again (producing `ENOTEMPTY` if the recursive removal eventually tries `rmdir`), but you got `EBUSY` (perhaps indicating that the file is being executed?).

It could be caused in some cases by interactive activity, but if that’s not the problem, make sure that all your resources are cleaned up and your processes joined before letting such an automatic cleanup run.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the problem. However, I am not quite sure what you mean by "your resources are cleaned up and your processes joined". Could you elaborate?

Comment: @ShadiRahimian: I don’t have all of your code, and might not know enough about TensorFlow to say exactly anyway, but the traceback shows that the interpreter is shutting down and we know that a file is still open.  The likely culprit for the latter is the `ImageDataGenerator`, since `fit_generator` expects it to produce data indefinitely.

Comment: You can also get the directory name by using `pdb`, which might indicate what subsystem is trying to clean up.  Or run `file` on the `.nfs…` remnant to identify its type.